# CertPathValidatorException for Android App users after moving server to different IP

Tags: android, ssl

Existing users of the Android app get the following error:

```
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException
```

This happend after using an existing certificate on a new server, this server is also hosted on a different IP. For this case a new system and IP is a requirement.

How would you approach this problem without making modifications to the Android App?